# Pass Unknown Number of Parameters to SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to executing stored procedures through vb.net. However, I was wondering if anybody knows how I can create a function in my database class to accept SP name and an unknown amount of parameters with their associated value to execute against a SQL database.

This would enable to execute any stored procedure designed to bring back a datatable using the same function in my class.

Any help would be great. I understand that there is a SqlParamaterCollection or could I use a parameter array?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Would you know what the names of the parameters are ahead of time or would that be something that you'd have to find out from the database?

Comment: I would know the name of the stored procedure and all parameters. My aim is to have one function that executes any procedure I pass through.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding default values in for parameters that you may not pass in.

W3Schools has a very good explanation on doing this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp)

And just in case this doesn't answer your question on how to do this in vb.net, there are several ways to handle this in code.  The most straightforward being an if statement.

```
if (there is a value to pass in then) then
     command.parameters.addwithvalue("@Parameter", your value)
endif
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for taking the time to reply to me. However, I understand I can create a sql connection and add parameters using addeith value etc but I am looking for a function that I can pass two arguments to. The first being the stored procedure name & the next a collection of parameters with their value. I was hoping I could pass these in & have code to execute a stored procedure by using the name argument & pass the collection of parameters.

Comment: You could only do this if all of the parameters in your stored procedure have default values, and the parameter collection you are passing into your function has a value for each parameter. For example, if you have 3 parameters in your stored procedure, your collection must have 3 items, with the unused ones being either NOTHING or dbnull.value.  I Hope I have understood the question correctly, and if this helps, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of what I am working on:

```
Public Sub CallSproc(SprocName As String, Server As String, Database As String, Optional ParameterArray(,) As String = Nothing)
```

Just create a two dimensional array to pass to your sub where the parameter name and value are passed. I break them apart using ubound and that will tell you how many parameters are in the array.